# How to search text in gitlab throughout many projects

Tags: gitlab

I have 20 projects in my gitlab repo and I wan't to search for a text throughout all projects in the web ui. It works with a single project, when I select it, but I don't know how to search through all of my projects.

I just hope that I didn't miss a small step, but I select `Your projects` and use the search bar. Don't know why this is so unintuitive compared to github.

Answer (score 1):

This is an EE feature that requires an ElasticSearch instance:

> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_global_search.html

Comment: So how do I add a ES instance?

Answer (score 0):

Try again with [GitLab 13.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/09/22/gitlab-13-4-released/#quick-navigation-using-the-search-bar) (September 2020)

> ### Quick navigation using the Search bar
>
> When navigating through GitLab, sometimes you just want to go to
> a specific project and not a search result page.
>
> Using the Global search bar, you can now quickly jump to recent issues, groups,
> projects, settings, and help topics. You can even use the `/` keyboard shortcut
> to move the cursor to the search bar, to navigate GitLab even more efficiently!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_4/enablement_global_search.gif -- Quick navigation using the Search bar]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/#autocomplete-suggestions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213699).